# Why doesn't my PostgreSQL helm dependency database exist when I try to connect?

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami, helm

Previously when I using the Bitnami Helm chart by way of Terraform to deploy PostgreSQL, I would have a database created. Now I no longer have a database created. I'm using

- same connect string
- same usernname
- same password

But I am getting this error in my Kubernetes logs,

> psql: error: FATAL:  database "foo" does not exist

Why is it that I no longer have an initial database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that is because

```
POSTGRES_USERNAME=foo
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foo
POSTGRES_DATABASE=foo
```

Works slightly different from,

```
POSTGRES_USERNAME=foo
POSTGRES_PASSWORD=foo
```

They both

- create the `foo` user and password
- will default to connecting to `foo` when you auth with user `foo`

But only one of them creates the database on initial run. [From the Bitnami documentation on the PostgreSQL chart](https://github.com/bitnami/containers/blob/main/bitnami/postgresql/README.md),

> By passing the `POSTGRESQL_DATABASE` environment variable when running the image for the first time, a database will be created. This is useful if your application requires that a database already exists, saving you from having to manually create the database using the PostgreSQL client.